# How do I access the message body from the Kynetx email endpoint?

Tags: email, krl

I want to extract a URL from an inbound email message and then http:get() the URL. How can I access the message body?

```
select when mail received from "(.*)@example.com" setting user
pre { /* extract first URL from message */ }
http:get(URL);
```

So what goes in the PRE block, given the following email message:

```
From: Example User <user@example.com>
To: x202 Endpoint <a101x202@kynetxapps.net>
Subject: An interesting URL

http://www.example.net
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `email:parts()` method to extract the portions of the email. In a multipart email, you will have both text/html and text/plain parts.

To access the email, you first extract the email (in RFC822 form) from the `msg` event param, like so:

```
envelope = event:param("msg");
```

Then, you can use the parts method to extract a portion. This code example extracts the plain text portion of the email:

```
textportion = email:parts(envelope,"text/plain").pick("$..text/plain");
```

Calling `email:parts(envelope)` without passing a mime filter will return a struct with all the parts of the email.

Once you have the body, you can use `textportion.extract(re//)` to extract information from the email body.